# Checkbox trigger change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am verifying certain data then I am dynamically checking checkbox and I want to trigger change event of checkbox.

```
$("#chk").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
```

Change event

```
$("#chk").change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                if (localStorage.getItem('A') == undefined && sessionStorage.getItem('A') == null) {
                    location.href = "/" + lang.split('-')[0] + "/login.aspx";
                }
                $("#dvClass").hide();
                $("#dvPromoCode").hide();
                $("#resultby").empty();
                $("#resultby").append('<option selected value="Flex">' + Res.flexidates + '</option>');
            }
            else {
                $("#dvClass").show();
                $("#dvPromoCode").show();
                $("#resultby").empty();
                $("#resultby").append('<option value="AirAvailability">' + Res.schedule + '</option>');
                $("#resultby").append('<option selected value="Flex">' + Res.flexidates + '</option>');
            }
        });
```

but it is not triggering the change event. But same if I execute from console than it works as expected. I want to know what can be issue.

Comment: I don't understand the question/problem.

Comment: Updated my question properly @D. Foley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  order of the function is important here.

You have place your change event before setting the checkbox values. Look at the below code.

```
 $("#chk").prop("checked", "checked").trigger("change");

 $("#chk").change(function() {
    alert("triggered!"); 
 });
```

The above won't work because when the jquery run for first line, it doesn't have any change event for the checkbox. You can check the same in this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qtjd2x8w/)

Now place your change event function before calling it like below.

```
 $("#chk").change(function() {
    alert("triggered!"); 
 });

 $("#chk").prop("checked", "checked").trigger("change");
```

Now you can get the expected result. You can check the same in this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qtjd2x8w/1/)

Always better to use the `on` event for the dynamic added elements like below.

```
$("#chk").on('change', function() {
    alert("triggered!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Be you sur you declared the change event before the prop change instr ; see updated answer :

```js
$(function(){
  $("#chk").on("change", function() {
    console.log(this.checked)
  });
  
  
  $("#chk").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
  

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: This will remove check from the checkbox

Comment: No still not :(

Comment: You're sur you declared the change code before the execution code , all of that inside the ready function

Comment: Oops adding change code before trigger works outs that wired :(